# Good tutorials/books for Java for the programmer with python background

Tags: java, python

Lately I have come to realize that I should know some of Java for programming ( I want to program in android). When I read all the tutorials and some free e-books, they either assume no programming experience or assume the reader to come from C/C++ background. Since I am used to python and MATLAB for a long time, the strong-typed C/C++ is clumsy for me to follow. Is there any tutorials/book some of you folks know that assumes reader to be a python programmer and guides him through Java showing the similarities and differences between the two languages?

I referred to following books and websites:

[Introduction to programming using Java by David J. Eck](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/) , which is nice but assumes little/no programming experience and have to go through many pages to get the basic.

> Java for Beginners by Ricardo Flask

This books moves to and fro without talking about user's background and other things.

This being said, I would like the book to answer few things like this right away and take through programming in Java:

-Why a function can be implemented without adding it to class in Java which can be done in python?
-What are the scope of various variables, their definition and how are they different from python?

These are few things python programmer will look in my opinion, when they try to see to Java.

Please suggest any materials that will help learning Java for python programmers.

Comment: I don't mind the haters but if they could suggest something despite their hate, that would make this awesome.

Comment: This [isn't an appropriate question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for SO - there is no 'right answer' - It's chatty and open ended.

Comment: DO you always expect for the right answer? I don't. I am not finding any source that says,"Java for python programmers". Can somebody give me a link or source? That would be right answer and I would instantly accept that. Right or wrong is how you look at it.

Comment: SO has guidelines for what questions are suitable for the site. This question doesn't follow that. Read the FAQ, and come back with a question about [a specific programming problem](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). It's a perfectly good question, but it doesn't fit SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used this book right after our introductory course to java at my university: [Object Oriented Design & Patterns,](http://www.horstmann.com/design_and_patterns.html) , by Cay Horstmann. It offers a good introduction to java as well to patterns. I liked it, and from there we went to just use online reference.

Good reading. And might I suggest the IntelliJ Idea Community edition as IDE when you feel like you need one.

Comment: See again! This book assumes C++.

Comment: Jack_of_All_Trades: It doesn't. It says it "Contains a crash course into Java for readers who are familiar with C++". It doesn't say the entire book is based on C++, and I know for a fact it isn't. We all learned java from this book, and we didn't know C++.